# is it to possible to get data from png with fopen?

Tags: c

is it to possible to get data from grayscale png with fopen and then convert it to integer numbers corresponding to grayscale?

```
FILE *fr;
int ch;
fr = fopen( "file_name.png", "rb" );
while ( (ch=fgetc(fr)) != EOF )
    printf( "%d", ch );
fclose( fr );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that easily, you can read about the file format at for example wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

I think your best option is to use some library like FreeImage to load the images.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is Yes! But to make sense of the read data, you need some [libraries](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html) or an in-depth knowledge of [how PNG files are structured](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html).

The library I've listed shows you step-by-step procedure of how to read png files.

Comment: would you be so kind and post some code how to just display the grayscale value with plglib? i am reading the text in your link but i am seriously confused

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't touch libpng.  Too complicated.

Try this:  http://nothings.org/stb_image.c

It's as easy as this:

```
unsigned char *image;
int x, y, n;
image = stbi_load("easy.png", &x, &y, &n, 4);
/* process image here */
stb_image_free(image);
```

Comment: thanks, I have one more question: is it possible to create png file with stb_image.c? I mean process image and than save it back to same png file.